# How to get live internet speed in android?

Tags: android, performance, android-studio

I want to build an application like this
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.internet.speed.meter.lite

so how can we get the most accurate internet speed every second

Comment: See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats or https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/NetworkStatsManager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, I can get live speed of internet using `NetworkStatManager` Class